# Is this how to say "I'm going to Japan Wednesday."?

Tags: grammar

Is

> 私は水曜日本に行きます。

a reasonable way to say "I'm going to Japan Wednesday."?

If it is, is this also okay?

> 水曜、私は日本に行きます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **need** to say 水曜日 rather than just 水曜.

It might also be preferable to use へ instead of に

but other than that your sentences will work.

> 私は水曜日、日本に行きます。

and

> 水曜日、私は日本に行きます。

Best per Tomono-san is

> 私は水曜日に日本へ行きます。

Comment: I'm sorry, are you really sure. We say, in informal way, 水曜、私は日本に行きます。And it is a bit difficult for me to
read 私は水曜日日本に行きます。without inserting comma between 水曜日 and 日本。Probably the politest and safest way of saying is 私は水曜日に日本へ行きます。

Comment: @KentaroTomono 聞いている方の予測レベルによって、話し言葉の「水曜」が使えないかもしれない。それ以外手伝ってくれてありがとう。

Comment: Not at all. 予測レベル? Probably you tried to mean 技能レベル？（ the level of Japanese ). Well, however you got the nicest answer so I'm not going to mess up here furthermore. Thank you.

Comment: @KentaroTomono 「技能レベル」ではなく、おおよそのレベルの意味の表現でミスしました。"mess up here furthermore"はどの意味が欲しかったですか。一切通じないです文。"nicest"よりこれ以外書いてないからこれを書きました。

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh...please let it end here. I think it will be a long conversation without scope. ( no offense please ).